# Beginner - Selecting a Row in Datagridview (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

sorry to bother with those stupid questions, but I'm very new into programming and can't find any solution, since my Problem seems to be so stupid, so noone ever asked about it before...
I'm coding a small Managment-System for my Inventory in an PenAndPaper-RPG.

I'm using a datagridview, where I can ADD and DELETE Rows with informations about an item into the DataGrid (Itemname, Amount, Info, and an Image)

My Problem is, i cant Access a selected row because i dont even know, HOW to select a row. If I click on an Item, i will select only one particular CELL.
But the Datagridview.SelectedRows.Count is always 0!

I hope, somebody understands my Problem. I will send a Picture to clarify my Problem. On the Picture you can see the cell "TestItem" is lit up. It means the cell is activated I guess.
I just Need to know how i can make sure, that the complete "ROW" is selected, when the user clicks on it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwAP2.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting the `SelectionMode` property of the datagridview to `FullRowSelect`? Refer to this MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/selected-cells-rows-and-columns-datagridview#to-get-the-selected-rows-in-a-datagridview-control

Comment: thank you so much....That was it. Ist amazing how "Basic" some Problems are, yet I don't find the solution for myself. Thank you!!